# How to always print an output with certain number of digits using AWK

Tags: linux, awk, text-formatting, numeric-data

I have the following command:

```
find . -mtime -5 -type f -exec ls -ltr {} \; | awk '{print "cp -p "$9" "$7}'
```

the output is like:

```
cp -p ./18587_96xxdata.txt 10
cp -p ./16947_96xxdata.txt 8
cp -p ./32721_96xxdata.txt 9
cp -p ./32343_96xxdata.txt 9
cp -p ./32984_96xxdata.txt 10
```

But I want the last part of the output to be always 2 digits, such as:

```
cp -p ./18587_96xxdata.txt 10
cp -p ./16947_96xxdata.txt 08
cp -p ./32721_96xxdata.txt 09
cp -p ./32343_96xxdata.txt 09
cp -p ./32984_96xxdata.txt 10
```

I tried different variations of `%02d`, but not getting what I want.

Here's one I tried:

```
find . -mtime -5 -type f -exec ls -ltr {} \; | awk '{print "cp -p " $9 " "("%02d", $7)}'
```

Should I be using `printf`, and if so, how  exactly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and then do this instead:

```
$ find . -mtime -5 -type f -printf "cp -p '%p' '%Ad'\n"
cp -p './bbbb.csv' '09'
cp -p './cccc.csv' '10'
cp -p './out1.txt' '09'
cp -p './out2.txt' '05'
```

Comment: could you please explain your answer a little further. I don't think I understand `%p` and `%Ad` parts. What if I want to print different columns (from the `ls -l` output) right next to the file name ?! Thank you!

Comment: `ls -l` presents information about a file. `find` and `stat` are 2 other commands that can also present information about a file, just like `ls` can. The output of `ls` is not parsable because it's designed for humans to read, not for machines to parse, so just don't do that. In my answer I'm using `find` to print some info about the files it finds. If you want other info then just add the `%whatever` strings to the printf to tell find to print that. Just look up the `find` man page to see what can be printed by using which %-strings.

Comment: thank you. I was looking at `man printf` and didn't see much there. However, `man find` is what I should be looking at. I didn't know `p` was `file name` and `Ad` was `day of month` util I read more about `find`. Thanks again!

Comment: I don't find the outputs to be very accurate. Ex:  for `-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 35314 Jul  6 19:47 ./95_96xxdata.txt`, I get the output of `cp -p ./95_96xxdata.txt 09` - it should be `06`. Not sure what's going on and there are several examples like this :(

Comment: I answered my own question - I should be using `%Td` instead of `%Ad` to get the `last modified time` - that's what I am after, not the `last access time`. Guess I am learning !

Answer (score 1):

Yep, `printf` is your friend. Use `%.2d` to 0-pad the number to 2 digits:

```
find . -mtime -5 -type f -exec ls -ltr {} \; | 
    awk '{printf "cp -p %s %.2d\n", $9, $7}'
```

To illustrate, I ran the following on a file containing your original output:

```
$ cat file
cp -p ./18587_96xxdata.txt 10
cp -p ./16947_96xxdata.txt 8
cp -p ./32721_96xxdata.txt 9
cp -p ./32343_96xxdata.txt 9
cp -p ./32984_96xxdata.txt 10
$ awk '{printf "%.2d\n", $NF}' file
10
08
09
09
10
```

---

Please note the very good point [raised by @edmorton](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/529424/22222). Parsing ls is very fragile. Ed's solution is far better.

Comment: When I ran your command, I am getting totally different output:  

    `cp -p 00 10  
    cp -p 00 8  
    cp -p 00 9  
    cp -p 00 9  
    cp -p 00 10`

Comment: @GA_t sorry, my bad. I had the fields in the wrong order. But please use [Ed's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/529424/22222) instead. This is really not a good approach.