# How to execute the output of a "find" command using "-exec"?

Tags: linux, find

This is related to my last question [[How to always print an output with certain number of digits using AWK](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/529421/how-to-always-print-an-output-with-certain-number-of-digits-using-awk][1]).

So, now I have the following command; the goal is to copy bunch of files into different directories based on certain factors:

```
find . -mtime -5 -type f -name '*data.txt' -printf "cp -p %p "/tmp/HTTPBackup/"%Td"/"\n"
```

This outputs:

```
cp -p ./32982_96xxdata.txt /tmp/HTTPBackup/09/
cp -p ./32312_96xxdata.txt /tmp/HTTPBackup/11/
cp -p ./32191_96xxdata.txt /tmp/HTTPBackup/07/
```

Now, how do I execute all these lines printed to the screen? Do I keep `-printf` and add `-exec`?

Ex:

```
find . -mtime -5 -type f -name '15692_96xxdata.txt' -printf "cp -p %p "/tmp/HTTPBackup/"%Td"/"\n" -exec {} \;
```

It didn't work; It was complaining that the permission was denied even though I own the file with 644 permissions - a simple copy works just fine.

```
cp -p ./15692_96xxdata.txt /tmp/http_backups/09/
find: ‘./15692_96xxdata.txt’: Permission denied
```

or replace `-printf` with `-exec` somehow? Not sure how to even try this.

Thank you!

Comment: Just pipe it to a shell by appending `| sh`

Comment: @L. Scott Johnson - just to make sure: `find . -mtime -5 -type f -name '*data.txt' -printf "cp -p %p "/tmp/HTTPBackup/"%Td"/"\n" | sh` - that's all I need to do? So, it doesn't really create a new shell script or anything, and all done in the background, right? I'd eventually need to set up a daily cron job to process new files each night. Thanks!

Comment: (1) `-exec {}` means “run the `.txt` file as a script”.  That’s why it was giving you a permission error — you don’t have *execute* permission on your `.txt` files.  Don’t use `-exec {}` unless your files are scripts; and even then, think hard about what you’re doing before you do it.  (2) Piping the output of `find` into `sh` should work and be safe if all your filenames are “normal”; i.e., made up of letters, digits, `_` and **`.`**.  If filenames can contain unusual characters, it can fail, perhaps harmfully. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) It seems a shame not to use `find`’s `printf` capability. But you can do what you want safely if you have the ```stat``` command and you’re willing to use it.

Comment: @G-Man - thanks for the explanation about the `-exec {}` and `.txt` permission issues. All of the files follow a strict naming convention without any unusual characters. They would have an `_`, but that's normal. I am not really sure if I understand your 3rd point though - we are using `find`'s `printf` ?? Please elaborate if I am missing something. thanks!

Comment: Sorry; I didn’t type everything I was thinking. I was thinking, piping the output of `find` into `sh` can fail, perhaps harmfully, if filenames can contain unusual characters.  There’s a safer solution — using `-exec` — but, to use that, we would need to get the files’ modification dates with the `stat` command, which would be less efficient.  I don’t see any way to combine `-exec` with the values (file attributes) that can be *reported to the standard output* with `-printf`.

Comment: @G-Man Seems like an `-execf` action would be handy

Answer (score 2):

You need those `-p`, `%p`, `/tmp/HTTPBackup/%Td` to be passed after %-expansion as separate arguments to the `cp` command. `xargs` could be used to do that splitting safely¹ if you print those arguments NUL-delimited (0 being the only byte value that can't occur in a file path or executed command argument):

```
find . -name '*data.txt' -mtime -5 -type f \
  -printf '-p\0%p\0/tmp/HTTPBackup/%Td/\0' |
  xargs -r0 -n3 cp
```

Or:

```
find . -name '*data.txt' -mtime -5 -type f \
  -printf '%p\0/tmp/HTTPBackup/%Td/\0' |
  xargs -r0 -n2 cp -p
```

---

<sup>¹ using a directory with a fixed name (`HTTPBackup`) in a world writable directory such as `/tmp` can be unsafe though.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

To have a regular answer I quote some comments given to the question.

*Just pipe it to a shell by appending `| sh`. just to make sure:*

```
find . -mtime -5 -type f -name '*data.txt' -printf "cp -p %p "/tmp/HTTPBackup/"%Td"/"\n" | sh
```

- *(1) `-exec {}` means “run the `.txt` file as a script”.  That’s why it was giving you a permission error — you don’t have execute permission on your `.txt` files. Don’t use `-exec {}` unless your files are scripts; and even then, think hard about what you’re doing before you do it.*
- *(2) Piping the output of `find` into `sh` should work and be safe if all your filenames are “normal”; i.e., made up of letters, digits, `_` and `.`.  If filenames can contain unusual characters, it can fail, perhaps harmfully.*